# helpers in Entity

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Suppose I have a `User` Model and here and there in my application I need to display his avatar with a link to his profile.

Now I find very useful to use the virtual properties. So in my `User` Entity file I did something like:

```
protected function _getAvatar()
{
    return "<a href='users\profile".$this-id."'><img src='".$this->avatar_url."'></a>";
}
```

So every time I need to show the avatar in a View I just write

```
<?= $user->avatar ?>
```

(it's just a semplified example to get the idea, not the actual code)

My question is: how can I make use of the Html helper in my User.php file?

But another question arises: even if the above code is very handy it seems to me that it breaks the MVC pattern. So is this the right way to to obtain what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being sceptical with good reason, that's really not how it should be done.

It's one thing to let entities mutate data in one way or another, but presentational logic, no, that's really too much, and helpers are for views! For now, simply use custom helpers, cells, or elements, and pass your entities to them instead.

In the future there may be [**entity presenters**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6698) available that might be better suited.

Comment: Thanks @ndm, happy to know that I'm not the only one tempted to put presentation logic in Entity and looking forward to use presenters. So I guess that the best solution for my issue is to use Elements or Cells, but I have a doubt about performance: suppose I have a page like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users). If I create an avatar Element to show the User image and informations won't the .ctp file be loaded hundreds of times affecting the performance?

Comment: @arilia Well, we could theorize about that all day, but I think you should just try it and see how it performs. In the end this also depends on how much traffic your app actually needs to handle. Cells and elements, despite being cacheable (note that both can be nested), might be rather slow, and if this turns out to be a problem, I'd suggest to either use a custom helper instead, or maybe even a caching proxy in case applicable.